# Уведомления на месте NavigationBar в IOS8 как в GoogleMaps или Skype

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone

Как показать такое уведомление как например показывают гугл карты если нажать кнопку home во время навигации или home во время разговора в скайпе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример скайпа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Система сама это показывает, когда ваш апп использует геоположение или микрофон соответственно.

Comment: создал тестовое приложение - и почему то не показывает, пример брал отсюда https://github.com/voyage11/Location

Comment: @Svyatoslavik статусбар становится синим только если апп работает с location services в режиме when in use

Comment: - может знаете где это в документации описано? - а то я не нахожу

Comment: @Svyatoslavik не знаю, поиск выдает что угодно кроме документации. Но в любом случае вам не стоит особо волноваться об этом, просто делайте свой апп так, чтобы он наиболее рационально использовал службы и другие ресурсы телефона, а Apple позаботится об остальном

Comment: @Svyatoslavik я могу точно сказать, что ни один апп не может напрямую управлять внешним видом статусбара, за исключением выбора цвета текста (белый или черный), показа индикатора активности сети и отрисовки его бэкграунда как части окна приложения. iOS сама решает все остальное - по этой же причине визуальная высота статусбара варьируется только на домашнем экране.